# how to specify href parameter for angular ui-bootstrap tabs directive

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using the angular ui-bootstrap library but i cant figure how to specify a custom **href** for each tabs.

```
<tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" active="tab.active" heading={{tab.name}}></tab>
```

In the angular ui-bootstrap docs, an optional parameter **select()** was specified but i have no idea how to use this is customizing the links for each tab

Another way to rephrase the question is how to use routing with angular ui-bootstrap tabs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I hope it's not too late, but I encountered the same problem today. You can achieve it by:

1) Defining tab hrefs in the controller:

```
$scope.tabs = [
  { title:"tab1", href:"#/route1/page1" },
  { title:"tab2", href:"#/route1/page2" }
];
```

2) Declaring a function to change hash in the controller:

```
$scope.changeHash = function(data) {
  window.location.hash = data;
};
```

3) Use the following markup:

```
  <tabset>
    <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}"
        active="tab.active" select="changeHash(tab.href)" />
  </tabset>
```

I'm not really sure on whether this is the best approach and I would love to hear from others.

Comment: It kind of worked for me - the layout worked, but as soon as I implemented the routing with the `select` and `changeHash` methods it seemed like the JS went in an endless loop and had tons of `Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached` errors. Seemed to toggle endlessly through tabs and then just fail.

Comment: This worked for me but when i refresh the page, its giving error `Error: [$rootScope:infdig]` and going back to home page instead of staying at the page i refreshed. Not sure how to resolve this.. :(

Answer (score 3):

When using angular-ui-router,you only need add an ui-sref attrib.
e.g.

```
<tabset>
    <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}"
    active="tab.active" ui-sref="stateName({param:somevalue,param2:tab.somekey})" /></tabset>
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the $rootScope:infdig error, I followed the instructions and changed the function to:

```
$scope.changeHash = function(data) {
    $location.path(data);
};
```

But remember to inject the $location service in the controller.